# What mistake am I making in my code?

Tags: python, csv, with-statement

For some reason my code doesn't seem to add to q, it prints out 0 for q even though there are 11 lines in the csv file, all I want to check if the csv file is empty, the code doesn't  work in my script, but in the python console it works fine.

```
with open('File.csv', 'r') as FILE:
    q=0;LS = reader(FILE, delimiter=',')
    for i in LS:
        q+=1
    print q
```

Can anybody tell me what mistake I making? I am really confused.

Comment: What do you mean by "it prints out 0 for q"? What are the contents of your CSV file?

Comment: It does not answer the question but using ; in python is bad practice, use another line.

Comment: If you print `i` inside the `for` loop you can quickly debug your code. I suspect `LS` is empty and therefore `q` stays 0.

Comment: You should specify where the reader comes from

Comment: reader comes from csv (see my post)

Comment: If you simply want to know if the file is empty or not, why not just `os.stat` and look at its size? If it's non-zero, the file isn't empty.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the file name is correct and in the same folder? I ran your script with a csv file I quickly made (contents: 1,2) and it outputted 1 as expected. Also make sure that your example code can be executed by itself, so include `from csv import reader` in the future.

Comment: yeah it has that line included, is there another way to check if a csv file is empty or not?

Comment: Well you can just read the file as a regular file, i.e.: 

fh = open('File.csv', 'r')
for line in fh:
        print line

Or just read the file with for instance cat.

Answer (score 1):

The `i` is iterating through the rows in `LS`, so if you have a file with 1 line it will be 1, if you have an empty file it will be 0, etc... I suspect your file is empty, or the opening did not succeed.

Comment: add some debug statements in the loop, such as `print i`, `print q` and see what happens.

Comment: I did it does print it out